# Guacamole 0.9.3 SSH private key to connect to AWS EC2 Linux Instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, private-key

Installed Guacamole 0.9.3 from source and war files on Ubuntu 14.04 and Tomcat 7 with MySQL authentication. RDP and SSH with password work fine. Have been trying to connect to AWS EC2 linux instances using Private Key. But when trying to connect it fails saying login failed. no idea what is going wrong. Need help to configure Guacamole connection to connect to AWS EC2 linux instance with private key

Answer (score 2):

If connecting to the very AWS instance you are running the guacamole-client from try using `localhost` as the *Hostname*. If connecting to another AWS instance be sure that your Security Group allows access from the Guacamole instance. Perhaps you can you your internal IP.

One thing that was preventing me from logging in to my AWS instances was that even though I set the correct Private Key I neglected to set an appropriate username in the Guacamole connection properties.

Comment: This should perhaps have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @nathan-tuggy, I've been a user of the site for many years but have never quite found a question that needed my input (in the form of an answer). With the sheer number of users here it is quite hard to get some traction and gain some rep to be able to utilize the site more effectively.

In this case I had just spent a good bit setting up Guacamole and somehow stumbled on this question. Since unanswered, albeit old, I wanted to share some ideas in case it would help others. Agreed that a comment would have been more appropriate, one day I'll get there.

Comment: Duly noted, although I found it straightforward enough once I got to editing posts, which anyone can do usefully.